# Chrome Browser errors and warning in debug.log file

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

```
[0111/073306:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 3020 not found in process
[0111/073306:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 3812 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 1424 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 968 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 1668 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 600 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 1904 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 3860 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[0111/073307:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 3844 not found in process
[0111/073307:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(61)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
```

I received the above in a debug.log file when taking a look at a process that runs in chrome and had failed. I use the Tampermonkey browser extension to run code to log in to a web page and start a process. The web page then remains open and the process continues to run. If the web page is disrupted, the process ends.

I am using the most up to date version of the browser extension Tampermonkey. I am not sure what these log files are telling me. Anyone with experience know what these are saying? I do not believe it to be an issue with the code that is used to start the process, but rather, something crashed in Chrome.

Chrome version: Version 55.0.2883.87 m